# Type Mismatch error when trying to insert index match formula using vba?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, formula

I am trying to insert the following index match formula with wildcards using vba like so:

```
Cells(i, 13) = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Contacts!$C:$C,MATCH(" * " & Range(""C"" & i).Value & " * ",Contacts!$B:$B,0)),"""")"
```

For some reason i get a type mismatch error. Please can someone show me what i'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

```
Cells(i, 13).Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Contacts!$C:$C,MATCH(""*"" & """ & Range("G" & i).value & """ & ""*"",Contacts!$B:$B,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(Contacts!$C:$C,MATCH(""*"" & LEFT(""" & Range("G" & i).value & ,7) """ & ""*"",Contacts!$B:$B,0)),""""))"
```

Comment: Quote characters need to be doubled up if included in a quoted text string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you put four double quotes to get the two, you need to put two to get one:

```
Cells(i, 13).Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Contacts!$C:$C,MATCH(""*"" & """ & Range("C" & i).Value & """ & ""*"",Contacts!$B:$B,0)),"""")"
```

Comment: Yeah, I see it now. I didn't include the nested quotes in my solution.

Comment: @Scott Craner thank you this works. Please see edited question. How can i add Left function to this code?

Comment: Please do not change a question after getting answers, it opens those who already answered to down votes.  Please roll back your question and ask a new question. @user7415328

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Cells(i, 13).Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Contacts!$C:$C,MATCH(""*" & Range("C" & i).Value & "*"",Contacts!$B:$B,0)),"""")"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that it is a formula with `.Formula` :

```
Cells(i, 13) = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Contacts!$C:$C,MATCH(""*" & Range("C" & i).Value & "*"",Contacts!$B:$B,0)),"""")"
```

Furthermore, your range  (""C"") wasn't properly recognized with your code

Answer (score 0):

With `abc` in C5 of the activesheet,

```
Dim i As Long
i = 5
With ActiveSheet
    .Cells(i, 13).Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Contacts!$C:$C,MATCH("" * " & .Cells(i, "C").Value & " * "",Contacts!$B:$B,0)),"""")"
End With
```

This produces the formula,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Contacts!$C:$C,MATCH(" * abc * ",Contacts!$B:$B,0)),"")
```

... in M5. I'm not entirely clear on whether you want the wrapping spaces or not.